# Is there a way to get boolean result if match is found in query string?

Tags: javascript, variables, url

Using javascript you can get variables from a URL. Like this:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable){
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

Is the URL says `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1&image=pic.jpg` then calling `getQueryVariable("id")` returns `1` and `getQueryVariable("image")` returns `pic.jpg`.

I would like to know a way to utilize boolean variables. I would like the function to return `true` or `false` is the variable is present. So with URL `http://www.example.com/index.php?id` calling `getQueryVariable("id")` returns `true`. If the `?id` is not present then I want it to return `false`.

<sup>This particular function is from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/).</sup>

---

I am using this function which I did not write and I'm afraid I don't understand it nor remember where it came from:

```
function getUrlVar(key){
    var result = new RegExp(key + "=([^&]*)", "i").exec(window.location.search); 
    return result && unescape(result[1]) || ""; 
}
```

Comment: I wonder why there is a close vote?

Answer (score 1):

If `vars[i]` doesn't contain a `=`, `pairs` will have only a single element. In this case `pair[1]` will return `undefined`. An easy way to fix this would be to change this:

```
if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
```

To this:

```
if(pair[0] == variable){return pair.length == 1 || pair[1];}
```

So if url parameter is just something like `?id`, the return value will be `true`, otherwise, it will be the value after the `=` sign.

Comment: @Bergi Whoops, yes thanks for pointing that out. (I was originally thinking of something like `pair.length > 1 && pair[1]` but that would return `false` for 'bool' value parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's preferable to convert the query part of the URL path to an associative array in the following way:

```
function createQuerySlots() {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var querySlotsAsStrings = query.split("&");
  var querySlotArray = [];
  var querySlots = {};
  for (var i=0; i < querySlotsAsStrings.length;i++) {
    querySlotArray = querySlotsAsStrings[i].split("=");
    querySlots[querySlotArray[0]] = querySlotArray[1];
  }
  return querySlots;
}
```

You can then retrieve query variable values:

```
querySlots = createQuerySlots();
value = querySlots.variable;
```

And you can test for the presence of a (Boolean) variable:

```
value = ("id" in querySlots);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function as follows:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable){
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1),
       vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){
             return true; // return true if match found
           }
   }
   return false; // no match found
}
```